# AWS SQS Listerner Unable to deserialize the message

Tags: amazon-web-services, jackson, amazon-sqs, message-listener

Jackson is unable to deserialize it. please find the stack trace and the SQS configuration and the listener

> ```
> org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.QueueMessageHandler.processHandlerMethodException(QueueMessageHandler.java:248)
>       t stack_trace   JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 's3': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true'
> ```
>
> or 'false')
> at [Source: (String)"s3://abc-invoices45-invoices/www-abc-at/2020/09/07/504000101-3436547667.pdf"; line: 1, column: 3]
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:722)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2867)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1913)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:772)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4340)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4189)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3205)
> at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:230)
> ...
> MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 's3': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token
> 'null', 'true' or 'false')
> at [Source: (String)"s3://abc-invoices/www-abc-at/2020/09/07/504000101-3436547667.pdf";
> line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token
> 's3': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token
> 'null', 'true' or 'false')
> at [Source: (String)"s3://abc-invoices/www-k24-at/2020/09/07/504000101-3436547667.pdf";
> line: 1, column: 3]

This is my SQS configuration

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import com.abc.properties.LocalPropertyService;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.QueueMessageHandlerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.SqsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;

@Configuration
@Import(SqsConfiguration.class)
public class InvoiceSqsConfig {

  @Bean(name = "amazonSQSAsyncClient")
  public AmazonSQSAsync getAmazonSQSAsyncClient(LocalPropertyService propertyService) {
    System.setProperty("invoice.queue.name",
                       propertyService.getString("sqs.invoice.queueName"));
    return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                                      .withRegion(
                                          propertyService.getString("sqs.aws.region"))
                                      .withCredentials(
                                          new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(
                                              propertyService.getString("sqs.invoice.accessKey"),
                                              propertyService.getString("sqs.invoice.secretKey"))))
                                      .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory() {
    QueueMessageHandlerFactory factory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setStrictContentTypeMatch(false);
    messageConverter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    factory.setMessageConverters(Collections.singletonList(messageConverter));
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
    factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    factory.setWaitTimeOut(20);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

And this is the Message Listener

```
import static org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS;

import com.abc.order.invoice.exception.InvalidInvoiceMessageException;
import com.abc.order.invoice.exception.OrderNotFoundException;
import com.abc.order.order.OrderService;
import com.abc.order.order.model.Order;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.annotation.NotificationMessage;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.annotation.SqsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InvoiceUpdateListener {

  @NonNull
  private final OrderService orderService;

  @SqsListener(value = "${invoice.queue.name}", deletionPolicy = ON_SUCCESS)
  @SneakyThrows
  public void receiveInvoice(@NotificationMessage EnvelopedMessage envelopedMessage) {
    log.debug("Received message from the invoice queue : {} ", envelopedMessage.getMessage());
    String message = envelopedMessage.getMessage();
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(message)) {
      throw new InvalidInvoiceMessageException("Received invalid message from the invoice queue");
    }
    String orderNumber = extractOrderNumber(message);
    Order order = orderService.getOrderByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
    if (order == null) {
      throw new OrderNotFoundException(
          "Could not find the order with order number : " + orderNumber);
    }
    order.setInvoiceUrl(message);
    log.debug("Saving invoice url for the orderNumber : {} ", orderNumber);
    orderService.save(order);
  }
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EnvelopedMessage {

  @JsonProperty("Type")
  private String type;
  @JsonProperty("MessageId")
  private String messageId;
  @JsonProperty("TopicArn")
  private String topicArn;
  @JsonProperty("Subject")
  private String subject;
  @JsonProperty("Message")
  private String message;
  @JsonProperty("Timestamp")
  private ZonedDateTime createdAt;
  @JsonProperty("SignatureVersion")
  private String signatureVersion;
  @JsonProperty("Signature")
  private String signature;
  @JsonProperty("SigningCertURL")
  private String certUrl;
  @JsonProperty("UnsubscribeURL")
  private String unsubscribeUrl;
}
```

and this is the message I receive from the producer

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "d77fa67e-6aa6-5b87-a707-f1ae5ba5922f",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:726569450381:invoices-from-core",
  "Subject" : "File uploaded: invoices/www-abc-at/2020/09/07/504000101-3436547667.pdf",
  "Message" : "s3://k24-invoices/www-abc-at/2020/09/07/504000101-3436547667.pdf",
  "Timestamp" : "2020-09-07T12:59:47.192Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "dummysignature",
  "SigningCertURL" : "dummy url",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "dummy url"
}
```

Comment: I think the input for SqsListener is the message itself. Could you try using String instead of NotificationMessage and dump the data to the console and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error suggests that the issue is around the `Message` key of your message.

The message you shared looks like it actually [comes from SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-and-json-formats.html#http-notification-json), this is a common pattern in which a producer posts a message into an SNS Topic, the SNS Topic publishes its messages in a SQS Queue and a consumer on the other side is triggered/polls the queue for messages.

In your case, what is happening is that your consumer expects the `Message` to be a JSON string like `"{\"some_key\": \"some_value\"}"` so after reading the value of the `Message` key in the enveloped message it tries to parse it to an actual dictionary/object.

You should either instruct your code to treat this value as an actual string and avoid conversion or enclose your message in a JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

got this working by making the following changes to the message listener

```
  public void receiveInvoice(@NotificationMessage String message) {
//
}
```

and removed this line messageConverter.setSerializedPayloadClass(String.class); from the Bean from InvoiceSqsConfig.java

```
@Bean
  public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory() {
    QueueMessageHandlerFactory factory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setStrictContentTypeMatch(false);
    messageConverter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    factory.setMessageConverters(Collections.singletonList(messageConverter));
    return factory;
  }
```